# Package nicematrix - "TeX capacity exceeded" error

Tags: capacity, nicematrix

I am trying to reproduce the example from Section 16.3 of the `nicematrix` manual:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\NiceMatrixOptions{nullify-dots,code-for-first-col = \color{blue},code-for-first-col=\color{blue}}
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
&   & \Ldots[line-style={solid,<->},shorten=0pt]^{n \text{ columns}} \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
\Vdots[line-style={solid,<->}]_{n \text{ rows}} & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
& 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\& 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

However, I keep getting the "TeX capacity exceeded" error.

I boiled it down to the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
    $\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
    &   & \Ldots & \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
    \Vdots & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 &  & 1 \\
    & 1 & 1 & 1 & \Ldots & 1
    \end{pNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

It still produces the same error.

P.S. I am compiling via TeXstudio on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

P.P.S. The full log file can be found here: https://pastebin.com/W6dVWMc9

Comment: I guess there is some very easy mistake I did - but I cannot understand what is wrong.

Comment: You should update your TeX installation. You are not using the newest version of `nicematrix`.

Comment: Hmm... The TeX Live I have is comparatively new. I just wonder, when I submit the paper (and it is going to be a scientific paper for a conference) - will the conference's TeX installation be able to compile my tex file?.. Just trying to find the safest solution.

Comment: What ouput do you actually intend? Your code puts a dotted line on the whole first line of the matrix and on the whole first column. Why not but it seems rather strange. I don't understand the mathematical interest of that construction...

Comment: MWE is just a stripped version of the example from Section 16.3 of the `nicematrix` manual (the first example in my post).

Comment: You are right. Well. I'm sorry (I'm the author of `nicematrix`) but you can't compile that example with your version of nicematrix  (nicematrix 2020/02/07 v3.11). Maybe you can provide the newest version of the file `nicematrix.sty` together with the files of your document to your editor.

Comment: If the newest version of `nicematrix.sty` is present in the same directory as your master TeX file, it will work.

Comment: Where can I find this file? Googling didn't really help...

Comment: Go [here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty) which provides all the versions of `nicematrix.sty`. The newest is on the top of the page (56256). Right click on `download` and save under the name `nicematrix.sty`.

Comment: Seems to work now. Thanks! Let's hope I can add *.sty file to my submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to that problem is to update the package `nicematrix`.